# How to run a program with a graphical processor by calling it with java code?

Tags: java, gpu, executable

I have a java program that calls an executable that is separate from the code itself.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Example.exe");
BufferedReader bri = newBufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader bre = newBufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

I use this part of the code to open Example.exe from the project directory and then use a bufferredReader to store the output, and it functions without error.  The only problem I've had is that the executable itself is very slow to complete since its very computationally taxing, and I've found that when left clicking and running the program independently with the windows graphical processor option it is much faster.  I suppose this might be due to the advantages of a GPU over CPU, but nonetheless I don't know how to call the run with graphical process option over the normal run (with CPU) option when calling from java code.  Is there any way to open it with that option, maybe indirectly through command prompt or even better with specific java code?

Comment: You should be able to right-click the .exe and select "change default graphics processor" (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this through the settings for your video card. There's a good [Autodesk knowledge base entry](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-force-your-laptop-to-Run-with-Graphics-Processor-vs-the-default-Integrated-Graphics-for-InfraWorks.html) that explains how to do this with Intel and AMD graphics cards. For newer versions of Windows 10 [this is now built into the operating system](https://www.howtogeek.com/351522/how-to-choose-which-gpu-a-game-uses-on-windows-10/).

Essentially you configure the graphics driver to recognize the executable you're running and have it launch with full GPU acceleration instead of integrated graphics. This should prevent you from needing to launch the application by hand. You may also be able to change the behavior by changing the power profile of your computer. If you change it from power saving (or balanced) to performance it shouldn't ever disable your integrated GPU.

All of that being said, it's not clear from your question that the application is actually using the GPU to perform its computations. If not, it could be that the application is bottle-necking elsewhere. Make sure you're draining the output stream from the application as quickly as you can. If you don't the application may be blocking waiting for more space in the output buffer to send to you.